# Redux action and modal window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux action which calls an api and returns an object. Profile object if it's performed successfully or error object if not. Everything works fine except one thing. I send the data through a modal window. If everything is ok, I just reload the page, if not, I don't want to reload the page, I want to display the errors.
ACTION:

```
export const addEducation = (eduData, history) => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post("/api/profile/education", eduData)
    .then(window.location.reload())
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      })
    );
};
```

API:

```
router.post(
  "/education",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const { errors, isValid } = validateEduInput(req.body);

    //Check validation
    if (!isValid) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id }).then(profile => {
      const newEdu = {
        school: req.body.school,
        degree: req.body.degree,
        fieldOfStudy: req.body.fieldOfStudy,
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to,
        current: req.body.current,
        description: req.body.description
      };

      //Add to exp array
      profile.education.unshift(newEdu); //Add the education to the beginning of the array opposed to push
      profile
        .save()
        .then(profile => res.json(profile))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json(err));
    });
  }
);
```

As you can see in the API code, I validate the input received and return the errors object if it's not passing.
Right now, the redux action reloads the page either way. How should I check if I have errors and prevent the page from reloading in the .then function?

Comment: Did you check the response inside `then`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code, I couldn't decipher any error. Maybe, you can 
try binding the .then response as well:

then(() => window.location.reload())

Also, try debugging or logging the response to check for the status code in error case.

Comment: I tried logging the response in the .then but it's not logging anything because the .catch is triggered. However, if I keep the reload in the .then it's reloading the page  and I think it also triggers the .catch at the same time.